# Set static IP address in OpenSUSE

Tags: networking, opensuse, static-ip

I need to set (static) the IP/Mask/Gateway of interface dev eth1 on my OpenSUSE server. Currently, the output of
`ip address show dev eth1` is:
[image: output of ip address show dev eth1]

I need to change it to 10.121.196.252/25 with a gateway of 10.121.196.10.
I've searched and can't seem to find a straight answer on this or other forums. Most responses recommend using ifconfig or a special application to make the change, but I have to believe that OpenSUSE *must* have a built-in tool to do such a basic task.

Note: The server does **not** have internet access and does **not** have ifconfig installed. These cannot be changed in the server's current environment.

Thanks in advance, folks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenSUSE leaves you with three alternatives:

- Use `yast` to configure the network
- Use Network Manager
- Use Wicked

I believe NM is the default, so you can use `nmtui` to edit the connection. `nmtui` can be installed with `zypper install NetworkManager-tui`

If you however do use yast, you can simply run `yast` and change the IP directly with yast. For a server with static IP, there's no need for Network Manager, so changing to managing it with `yast` should also be fine. YaST (Yet Another Setup Tool) *is* the builtin SuSE tool for configuration.

Comment: It looks like my installation of openSUSE does not have YaST installed (or it is disabled). This is probably because the installation ISO is non-standard. At any rate, I was able to figure out how to do it. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The fix turned out to be possible to set the IP address of the known eth device using `ip addr` commands:

```
ip addr del [IP]/[netmask i.e. 24] dev eth#
ip addr add [IP]/[netmask i.e. 25] dev eth#
```

I'm not sure why this solution is not presented easier to find. Nevertheless, this was the solution I needed.

Comment: That's ephemeral, and will only last until the next reboot - and perhaps not even that long. DHCP daemons running may overwrite it when renewing the lease.